# jQuery HTTP .post - how to compare received data

Tags: jquery

my HTTP Post gives back some data. In this case a simple T if the user exists, otherwise an F. These letters are received fine, if i log them they're shown just the way they should be. But i need to do an if-statement with 'data', but even if data contains T if(data == 'T') doesnt return true.

Here is the code:

```
        $.post('url, {username: loginName }, function(data){
                if(data == 'T'){
                    alert("Username already exists!");  
                }else{
                    alert("Username not taken yet!");
                }
            });
```

Is there any special way to deal with the data?

Comment: can you do a `console.log(data)` and see what is the value of `data`

Comment: Can you provide sample T values

Comment: Yep, already done: Just showing a simple 'T'

Comment: What's the Content-Type of the URL? Make sure there are no white spaces when returning data.

Comment: Content Type is text/html

Comment: @TobiasKuess may be there are trailing/leading spaces... can you try `console.log(':' + data + ':')`

Comment: @TobiasKuess can you trim it and test like `if($.trim(data) == 'T'){`

Comment: Jesus Christ, it was a leading space. I dont know where it comes from, but i am glad you could help me, thank you so much!! It was getting pretty frustrating..

Comment: try using boolean true and false instead of T and F strings it will avoid the trailing spaces

Comment: @TobiasKuess most of the times it is those simple things that causes problems :( - and finding out what are the actual and expected values are the most important step in debugging those

Comment: @TobiasKuess in terms of solution I would not suggest using `$.trim()` you need to fix the source of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems that the cause of the problem is on the leading/trailing spaces on returning the `data`.

If you are using PHP on the `url`, I strongly suggest set the `Content-Type` to `text/plain` (using `header()` function)and trim the data on the source code of the `url` using `trim()` PHP function.